# Why do the conic sections differ in these two envelopes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

I graphed a square with sides:

> $y=x$
>
> $y=-x+40$
>
> $y=x+40$
>
> $y=-x$

Then I divided each side to 20 equal parts and drew lines through points:

> $(1,39)$ & $(19,19)$: (line 1)
>
> $(2,38)$ & $(18,18)$: (line 2)
>
> etc.

Then I found the equation of the envelope of the set of lines by finding 5 intersection points (between lines 1 & 2, 2 & 3, . . .) and plugging them in the formula: $$\frac{A}{F}x^2+\frac{B}{F}xy+\frac{C}{F}y^2+\frac{D}{F}x+\frac{E}{F}y+1=0$$

After simplifications I found the envelope equation to be: $$-y^2-40x+40y+1=0$$

Which is obviously a parabola.

But then I decided to find the equation of envelope of the set of lines in another two sides of the square:

> line 1: through points $(-1,39)$ & $(19,21)$
>
> line 2: through points $(-2,38)$ & $(18,22)$
>
> etc.

Again I found the intersection points of the lines 1 & 2, 2 & 3, . . . and placed them in above formula.

After simplifications I found the envelope equation to be: $$178749x^2+165738xy+138115y^2-5552223x-4092601y+36030=0$$

Which is an ellipse!

Why do the conic sections differ while both the envelopes are the same and they are just rotated in resepct to each other?

Comment: I've done the same now with GeoGebra, and get for the second equation: $$x^2 = -40y + 1201$$ which is a parabola.

Comment: Anyway, bear in mind these are only approximations of the real envelopes, whose equations are $y^2=40y-40x$ and $x^2=-40y+1200$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Why did I reach an ellipse? Did I calculate something wrong? I graphed your parabolic equation and my elliptical one, and they were tangent with a very good approximation.

Comment: Perhaps both are true? Because in the Wikipedia article for [ellipse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), under the title *Steiner generation*, these intersection points are a way of generating an ellipse.

Comment: I don't know, but can give you the coordinates of the five points I found: $$(17, 22.8)\quad(15,24.4)\quad(13,25.8)\quad(11,27)\quad(9,28).$$

Comment: Exactly my coordinates too. Also, my ellipse goes through $(0,0)$.

Comment: In fact, they both share 4 of the 5 points except for $(17,22.8)$. I mean my ellipse and your approximated parabola.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Of course my ellipse is an approximation too.

Comment: Point $(0,0)$ is clearly wrong. That's why you get an ellipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150018/discussion-between-etack-sxchange-and-intelligenti-pauca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Configuration described in the question]

Usually you would define the envelope not as the conic passing through 5 intersection points, but tangent to five of the lines. So you would compute the dual conic first (i.e. the conic defined as a set of tangent lines), and then the primal from that (i.e. the conic as a set of incident points).

Doing that for your first set you get the dual conic as

$$(a,b,c)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}20&20&1\\20&20&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=0$$

so a line $ax+by+c=0$ is tangent to the conic if it satisfies the quadratic equation above. The primal conic is then any multiple of the inverse of that matrix, so you get that as

$$(x,y,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&0&20\\0&1&-20\\20&-20&0\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

which is a parabola since the determinant of the top left $2\times 2$ matrix is zero. You may write this as $-y^2-40x+40y=0$ which is close to the $-y^2-40x+40y+1=0$ you have in your question but not quite the same as the constant term differs.

For your second set of lines you get

$$(a,b,c)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}20&0&0\\0&60&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=0
\\
(x,y,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&20\\0&20&-1200\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

which is again a parabola. You might also write it as $x^2=1200-40y$ if you prefer, which is an equation already discussed in the comments. Or as $y=30-\frac1{40}x^2$ which may be even more familiar as the equation of a parabola.

But even if using the tangents instead of intersections is the correct way of getting the envelope correctly without any approximation, if you were using intersections in a symmetrical way you should get a symmetrical result. So let's check. Here are the first 5 points of intersections of consecutive lines for your first set (the decimal numbers are exact, not rounded):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}2.8\\37\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}4.4\\35\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}5.8\\33\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}7.0\\31\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}8.0\\29\end{pmatrix}\\
(x,y,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&0&20\\0&1&-20\\20&-20&-1\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}=0
$$

So your $-y^2-40x+40y+1=0$ with its constant term is correct here. For the second set of lines you get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}17\\22.8\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}15\\24.4\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}13\\25.8\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}11\\27.0\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}9\\28.0\end{pmatrix}\\
(x,y,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&20\\0&20&-1201\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}=0
$$

Again a parabola. Again almost the same as what you get from the tangents, except for a shift by $1$ in the constant term. And again an equation which has already been given, namely as $x^2 = -40y + 1201$ in one of the comments.

I don't know where you got that equation of an ellipse from, but I suggest you check the computation leading to that. Probably no conceptual problem there but just a typo somewhere or something like that.